# Merge elements from JSON array in Redshift

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-redshift

Having the following JSON data in a column of `text` type in a Redshift database

| genres |
| --- |
| ["drama","action","comedy"] |
| ["drama","comedy","thriller"] |
| ["drama","romance"] |

I'd like to combine them to text using a custom delimiter to something like

| genres |
| --- |
| drama|action|comedy |
| drama|comedy|thriller |
| drama|romance |

I see that there are some [solutions available in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array), but my question is how to accomplish the same in Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Since `genres` is json-compliant, you can use the super type, PartiQL, and some list aggregation to accomplish this.

Let's make some tables.

```sql
create temporary table _so (
  genres text
);

insert into _so values
  ('["drama","action","comedy"]'),
  ('["drama","comedy","thriller"]'),
  ('["drama","romance"]');
```

The basic pattern here is to convert your column into the super type (`supered`), use PartiQL to pivot the values into rows (`super_pivot`), then aggregate those string values after converting them back into strings. (`lag`).

```sql
with supered as (
  select 
    json_parse(genres) genres
  from
    _so
), super_pivot as (
  select
    sup.genres,
    item
  from
    supered as sup,
    sup.genres as item
), lag as (
  select
    genres,
    listagg(cast(item as varchar), '|') delimited
  from
    super_pivot
  group by
    genres
)
select * from lag;
```

Note that this presumes `genres` is unique. If it is not, perhaps make a `row_number` or something to aggregate on later so you end up with the same number of rows as your starting point.

| genres | delimited |
| --- | --- |
| ["drama","comedy","thriller"] | drama|comedy|thriller |
| ["drama","action","comedy"] | drama|action|comedy |
| ["drama","romance"] | drama|romance |